# MySQL C# - MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

i just followed a tutorial and now is stucked with a "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException" - Exception and "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts".

What is causing those? The Credentials are all right.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(@"Data Source=appm52;port=3306;Initial Catalog=test;User Id=skaratekedb;password=***");
    int i;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i = 0;
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from login where username = '" + textBox1.Text + "' and password= '" + textBox2.Text + "'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());

        if (i == 0)
        {
            label3.Text = "you have entered invalid username pr password";
        }
        else
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form2 fm = new Form2();
            fm.Show();

        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Data Source=appm52:3306;Initial Catalog=test;User Id=skaratekedb;password=***

Comment: that did'nt helped still: Ein Ausnahmefehler des Typs "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException" ist in MySql.Data.dll aufgetreten.
Zusätzliche Informationen: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Comment: The tutorial told you to concatenate strings in a query? This is HIGHLY insecure and wide open to injection attacks. As for your error, the problem is your connection string isn't pointing to your serve (or the server isn't running). Check that everything is running and that your string is correct for what i assume is a local database on your system.

Comment: the typical syntax for a mysql connection is `Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
Pwd=myPassword;`

Comment: your connection string looks like a MS SQL Server style of string, rather than MySQL. Try Takarii's suggestion first. And whatever tutorial you used that suggested building queries in this way needs to be removed from the internet, it's promoting insecure coding practices that will eventually get your database hacked. You need to use parameterised queries for better protection against SQL injection attacks. You can find guidance on that for the .NET/MySQL combination via the official site and in lots of other examples.

Comment: i'll try now the tutorial on the official site: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-open.html

Comment: After using the tut on the official site and putting the project to the C:/ it worked. Thank you all for your help!